# how to connect SQL Server cubes using dotnet(C#)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to this cubes concept in SQL Server. I need to connect to cubes and query and get a result and display that result in grid view

Any help would be great telling how to connect to a cube, articles on it, code any thing  that can help me to  achieve the result

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the official Microsoft [SQL Server Analysis Services Tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx) for some background information.

Here's a C# [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CubesAdomd.aspx) that shows what cubes, MDX, Analysis Services and so forth are and how to get to use them from your C# application.